# Why push notifications arrives on iPhone 4S after delay as compared to my iPod Touch 4 at same wifi?

Tags: iphone, ios5, notifications, ipod-touch

I have two devices: iPhone 4S and iPod Touch 4. They have the same iOS 5.0.1. I find an interesting behavior: my iPod Touch usually gets the notification from Mail or other apps first. Then about 10 seconds later or maybe longer, my iPhone 4S gets the same notification. This occurs even if they share the same wifi. Does anyone meet the same issue? Or Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

Given the choice between WiFi and 3G, APNS will prefer to use 3G, so the Push Notification to the iPhone are arriving through 3G if it is possible.

You can test disconnecting from 3G and so both devices will use the same network.

Comment: Where is your source for this? The question says that the iPod Touch gets the notification first - that doesn't have 3G, so why should it get it first.

Comment: @Nick Bull, I know it 'cause I have proved it. iPod Touch get it first as 3G is always slower for Push Notification and so iPhones get push notification slower. I suppose it is because of 3g lags opening connection to device. Believe it or not, that is what I have learned working for a year with APNS capable apps. I have developed server side as well as device app. I think I know something about that.

Comment: That's interesting. I just did a quick search and found this [urban airship](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60714-troubleshooting-push-delivery) which says pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the push notification isn't immediate. It depends on server loads, network congestion, etc.

I've got an app that sends a push notification to a few thousand people. I've been sat in a room with 10 devices (a number of iPhones, iPads, and iPod touches) all on the same wifi connection and the push notification has varied between them all and can be up to 30 seconds at times.